# Create StandardPasswordEncoder Password hashes from within ruby

Tags: ruby, spring, puppet

We're running different java applications which uses org.springframework.security.crypto.password.StandardPasswordEncoder to store and read password hashes to guarantee privacy for all user passwords.

We deploy these applications via puppet and manage all configuration data into hieradata (eyaml).
Now we want to store all passwords in encrypted yaml files and create the hashes from within puppet.
For that purpose we want to create a puppet (ruby) function to create password hashes in the correct hash format.

StandardPasswordEncoder seems to be an special spring class for encrypting passwords. Is there a way to create such hashes from ruby?

Comment: you can use `bcrypto-ruby` https://github.com/codahale/bcrypt-ruby

Comment: But isn't an other hash algorithm used in bcrypt-ruby, just bcrypt. And StandardPasswordEncoder is an sha256 hash method?

Comment: O sorry in this case you can use digest, I will put the code bellow

Answer (score 0):

You can use Digest to create hash in ruby, its a core library https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.0/libdoc/digest/rdoc/Digest/SHA2.html

```
require 'digest'

# Compute a complete digest
Digest::SHA2.hexdigest 'abc'          # => "ba7816bf8..."
Digest::SHA2.new(256).hexdigest 'abc' # => "ba7816bf8..."
Digest::SHA256.hexdigest 'abc'        # => "ba7816bf8..."

Digest::SHA2.new(384).hexdigest 'abc' # => "cb00753f4..."
Digest::SHA384.hexdigest 'abc'        # => "cb00753f4..."

Digest::SHA2.new(512).hexdigest 'abc' # => "ddaf35a19..."
Digest::SHA512.hexdigest 'abc'        # => "ddaf35a19..."

# Compute digest by chunks
sha2 = Digest::SHA2.new               # =>#<Digest::SHA2:256>
sha2.update "ab"
sha2 << "c"                           # alias for #update
sha2.hexdigest                        # => "ba7816bf8..."

# Use the same object to compute another digest
sha2.reset
sha2 << "message"
sha2.hexdigest                        # => "ab530a13e..."
```

Comment: Thanks for that code but it seems that the generated hashes doesn't the same like from StandardPasswordEncoder.
Documentation of StandardPasswordEncoder say: "A standard PasswordEncoder implementation that uses SHA-256 hashing with 1024 iterations and a random 8-byte random salt value." and it seems that this is the difference between these both classes.

Comment: @ChristianMeißner i just checked the documentation of [StandardPasswordEncoder](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.2.4.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/crypto/password/StandardPasswordEncoder.html) and they recommendation is use [BCryptPasswordEncoder](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.2.4.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/crypto/bcrypt/BCryptPasswordEncoder.html) for more security and compatibility with other languages

Comment: Yeah, I know. But we can't simply let it change. Our vendor decided once to use this function but don't read this warning, I guess.
Now we have the situation as described. 
We have also many other hashing algorithms in the wild so we have to handle the creation of hashes in a wider way.